# Insert new line in table

Tags: tables

I am trying to put part of a header of a table on a new line.

This is my code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\begin{document}
\title{}
\author{My name}
\date{\today}
\maketitle

\section{}


\begin{table}[!htbp] \centering 
  \caption{This is a table} 
  \label{} 
\begin{tabular}{@{\extracolsep{5pt}} lll} 
\\[-1.8ex]\hline 
\hline \\[-1.8ex]
\textbf{Rownames} & \textbf{Quite a long}\\\textbf{header} &  \textbf{Short header} \\ 
\hline \\[-1.8ex] 
value & $1.330$ & $1.080$ \\ 
value & $0.440$ & $0.360$ \\ 
value & $0.730$ & $$-$0.380$ \\ 
\normalsize 
\end{tabular} 
\end{table} 


\end{document}
```

This is output:

[image]

The output table I want should look like:

[image]

Note how in my desired output, only the word "header" of "Quite a long header" is on a new line. How can I achieve this table?

Comment: If you pay attention to Mico's answer, his way is more robust. You may want to consider reading it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We adjust the column type to `p{<length>}` so that we can introduce paragraphs and call the `array` package to use the option `>{\raggedright}`. Here is the change in the code:

```
\begin{tabular}{@{\extracolsep{5pt}} l>{\raggedright}p{8em}l}
```

[image]

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage{array}
\begin{document}
\title{}
\author{My name}
\date{\today}
\maketitle

\section{}


\begin{table}[!htbp] \centering 
  \caption{This is a table} 
  \label{} 
\begin{tabular}{@{\extracolsep{5pt}} l>{\raggedright}p{8em}l} 
\\[-1.8ex]\hline 
\hline \\[-1.8ex]
\textbf{Rownames} & \textbf{Quite a long header} &  \textbf{Short header} \\ 
\hline \\[-1.8ex] 
value & $1.330$ & $1.080$ \\ 
value & $0.440$ & $0.360$ \\ 
value & $0.730$ & $-0.380$ \\ 
\normalsize 
\end{tabular} 
\end{table} 


\end{document}
```

Comment: If you replace `$$-$0.380$` with `$-0.380$`, LaTeX will use the typographically correct "minus" symbol instead of the "hyphen-dash" symbol.

Comment: @Mico Sorry I was just addressing the issue of the table headers.

Answer (score 9):

You may want to do the following:

- Use a `tabularx` environment instead of a `tabular` environment, and use the `X` column type for the headers of columns 2 and 3. In the example below I've chosen the `X` column type for the first row as well, but depending on the "real" contents of that column you may prefer to set its type to `l`. I came up with a total width of `9cm` for the `tabularx` environment; depending on the size and other characteristics of the font you use, you may need to change that width a bit.
- Use the `dcolumn` package for the numbers in columns 2 and 3, so that the numbers are aligned on their decimal points; the contents of a column of type `D` will by typeset in math mode automatically, hence no need to encase the numbers in pairs of `$` symbols.
- Use the `booktabs` package and its commands `\toprule`, `\midrule`, and `\bottomrule` instead of the basic `\hline` command.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage{tabularx,dcolumn,booktabs}
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[!h] 
\centering 
  \caption{This is a table} \label{} 

\smallskip
\begin{tabularx}{9cm}{X*{2}{D{.}{.}{2.3}}}
\toprule
\textbf{Rownames} & 
\multicolumn{1}{Y}{\textbf{Quite a long header}} &  
\multicolumn{1}{Y}{\textbf{Short header}} \\ 
\midrule
value & 1.330 & 1.080 \\ 
value & 0.440 & 0.360 \\ 
value & 0.730 & -0.380 \\ 
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx} 
\end{table} 
\end{document}
```

---

*Addendum*: If, in addition, you wanted the numerical entries *right-aligned* and automatically rounded to two places after the decimal marker (both of these seem to be indicated from the sample table you've posted), I would recommend that you also load the `siunitx` package and provide suitable options to the package's `S` column type.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage{tabularx,booktabs,siunitx}
\sisetup{round-mode=places,
         round-precision=2,
         table-format=2.2,
         table-number-alignment=right}
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[!h] 
\centering 
  \caption{This is another table} \label{} 
\smallskip
\begin{tabularx}{9cm}{ X *{2}{S} }
\toprule
\textbf{Rownames} & 
\multicolumn{1}{Y}{\textbf{Quite a long header}} &  
\multicolumn{1}{Y}{\textbf{Short header}} \\ 
\midrule
value & 1.330 & 1.080 \\ 
value & 0.440 & 0.360 \\ 
value & 0.730 & -0.380 \\ 
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx} 
\end{table} 
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 7):

If you want to manually provide the line-breaking, you can use a macro like `\Stack` and friends:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{booktabs}% http://ctan.org/pkg/booktabs

\newcommand{\Stack}[3][]{#1\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}#2@{}}#3\end{tabular}}
\newcommand{\StackR}[2][]{\Stack[#1]{r}{#2}}
\newcommand{\StackL}[2][]{\Stack[#1]{l}{#2}}
\newcommand{\StackC}[2][]{\Stack[#1]{c}{#2}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{lrr} 
  \toprule
  \textbf{Rownames} & \StackC[\bfseries]{Quite a long \\ header} & \textbf{Short header} \\
  \midrule
  value & $1.330$ & $1.080$ \\ 
  value & $0.440$ & $0.360$ \\ 
  value & $0.730$ & $-0.380$ \\
  \bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

The [`makecell` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/makecell) provides a similarly-named `\makecell` macro that does... something similar.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a way to do things with makecell and booktabs:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{makecell, booktabs}

\begin{document}
\title{}
\author{My name}
\date{\today}
\maketitle

\renewcommand{\theadfont}{\bfseries}
\section{}

\begin{table}[!htbp] \centering
\caption{This is a table}
\label{}\sffamily
\begin{tabular}{ l@{\qquad} r @{\qquad} r}
\addlinespace
\toprule
\toprule
\thead{Rownames} & \thead{Quite a long\\ header} &  \thead{Short header} \\
\midrule
value & 1.330 &  1.080 \\
value & 0.340 &  0.360   \\
value & 0.730 & $ - $0.380 \\
\bottomrule
\normalsize
\end{tabular} 
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image: Result:]